# Loop through a form which contains another form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to loop through a form with Javascript but my problem is that I have another form in the first form.

I'd like to loop through the first form only, not the inner one. I found this method on an other post :

```
var table = $("#table_cultures tbody");

table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        productId = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();

    // do something with productId, product, Quantity

    alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nId: ' + productId
           + '\nProduct: ' + product
           + '\nQuantity: ' + Quantity);
});
```

This method works but loop through the both forms.

**EDIT 1 :**

The html looks like :

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Something here</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <form>
                     <table>
                         //tr td ...
                     </table>
                 </form>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML so we can see what you need, please?

Comment: It''s kind of bad thing - having form in form. Not all of the browsers will manage to handle this. Some of them, will just erase one of them

Comment: @xAqweRx I understand, and I know it but I can't do without it, it's something asked by my superior :/

Comment: @SteeveDroz I edited with an example but I can't add the entire code that I have, it's too huge, sorry :/

Comment: nesting of <form> is not valid

Comment: It is a bad practice to nest forms like that

Comment: What for do you need nested forms? That could be done without it

Answer (score 1):

nesting of `<form>` elements is not allowed

please see:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

> "...Flow content, but with no form element descendants..."